# Locating studs behind cultured marble

Tags: studs

I want to install an ADA grab bar over cultured marble that is attached to durock cement board. My stud finder and an enhanced stud find sees nothing.

Is the a way to find the studs?

Comment: Any chance it is not in the shower section but outside of it and there are switches/outlets on the wall?  Does the marble go all the way to the ceiling?

Comment: Franklin makes a great stud finder. Most only have one or two sensors, the new franklin ones have 13. Even still, you may have a problem due to the density of the marble.

Comment: Sometmes you can find studs on the other side of the wall from the shower and you will at least know how many there are and approximately where they are. I am approaching age 80 and I am a little wobbly on my feet. As a result I have become a fanatic about grab bars in showers (especially in the tub shower I use). I find and use studs whenever I can, but I have found plastic anchors hold wonderfully in ceramic tile on backerboard. You do not have screw into studs. I drill the correct size hole specified for the heavy duty plastic anchor and use the ss screws w/ the bar.  I have had no failure.

Comment: Is this a shower or is it a tub/shower? If it is tub shower you absolutely need a proper dimpled friction mat even with grab bars. Where is this house located? The best tub mat is the kind advertised for "refinished tubs" even if your tub is not refinished. They provide the needed friction but pull up easily.

Comment: Tell us about the other side of the wall, please. (And while wingits are great, they do require a huge hole, which is incompatible with some bars.)

Answer (score 3):

Get a wicked<sup>*</sup> strong magnet.

Like, really, really wicked strong, and go looking for screw-heads.

Mark each one in pencil and connect the dots.

<sup>*</sup>*New England slang usage - emphatically really very...*

Comment: Old hard drives have very wicked strong magnets.  Do not put any part of your skin between two of them.

Answer (score 3):

Sometmes you can find studs on the other side of the wall from the shower and you will at least know how many there are and approximately where they are.  I find and use studs whenever I can, but I have found plastic anchors hold wonderfully in ceramic tile on backerboard. You do not have to screw into studs to securely attach a grab bar. I drill the correct size hole in the ceramic specified for a good quality heavy duty plastic anchor and use the stainless steel screws provided with the grab bar. I have had no failures.

Plastic anchors are however not "recommended" in ADA instructions. What is recommended is one of the Wingits or other similar mounting devices which require a larger hole, maybe up to 3/4". These clamp onto the inside of the wall and reportedly will make a secure attachment of a grab bar onto ordinary drywall.

For cultured marble on concrete backer if there is no stud where you want the bar there is another possibility: adhesive attached grab bars. The original one of this type was made in Germany for attaching grab bars to granite walled showers in high end rental housing in the case where the renter wants a grab bar, but the landlord does not want holes drilled in the granite. I have never installed one of these, but I think they are an effective method AND CAN BE EASILY REMOVED. The adhesive remains soft and can be scraped off and the bar removed. Reportedly there is no trace the bar was ever there.

I discovered how well plastic anchors work when I was installing a vertical grab bar at the entrance to the high step over tub shower an elderly relative was going to use while visiting our house. I interpreted my stud finder as indicating there was a stud where I want to put the bar and I marked four holes. My masonry bit went through the ceramic tile, through the 1/2" backer and through the 1/2" drywall behind that. . . into empty space. &^%$#@

Drilled the other 3 holes into empty space, inserted "good" plastic anchors, used the stainless steel screws that came with the bar. SOLID AS CAN BE FOR 15 YEARS.

"No drilling required grab bars" are shown on the HomeDepot website up to 24 inches long. I have not used these. I have installed maybe 15 grab bars in three different houses (but not for compensation as I have no business liability insurance) and have had no failures.

EDIT

A properly framed bathroom has horizontal "blocking" in the walls of showers and tub showers at the proper height for grab bars. Make sure you test for the possibility you have that. That would greatly simplify installing grab bars.

If you really care about finging studs or blocking you might spend for a "Walabot". This device might locate studs or blocking through marble/cultured marble. I have not been willing to buy one so I cannot report on its effectiveness.

EDIT2

I am approaching age 80 and even though I can walk well outside in the open, I have had some tripping falls so I have become a fanatic about grab bars in showers.

You really need a minium of two bars for a proper installation in a tub/shower. I have an 18" bar vertically oriented at shoulder height at the edge of the tub/shower I use (control wall on the right facing the tub from outside) and a horizontal 36" bar on the long wall at a height of 37" above the bottom of the tub. This is higher than the ADA recommendation but I prefer it.

To enter the tub (friction mat in place), I grasp the 18" bar with my right hand, lift my left leg over the side of the tub and plant my left foot on the mat as I reach for and grip the 36" bar with my left hand. Only then do I lift my right leg over the side of the tub.

EDIT3

It can be that one stud is in the right place for one end of a bar but there is no stud at where you would like to place the other end of the bar. In that case screw into the one stud and use anchors or Wingits at the other end. In my case I had a 36" bar on hand and no stud was in the correct place in my shower for either end of the bar so I just used four plastic anchors (two on each end). It is solid ten years on.

My wife is mobility impaired and uses a walk-in low step over shower (control wall on the left, entry at far end). I installed three bars: 18" horizontal on far wall for entry, 42" horizontal on long wall, 18" on control wall. The bar on the control wall should be horizontal, but she wanted vertical so that's what she got. A horizonal bar on the control wall is supposed to allow a person facing the controls to hold on while adjusting the controls and be a wide target for an emergency reach.

A towel rack is 8 inches outside the shower in a wall in the plane of the end wall of the shower. It is a sturdy 1" diameter 24" long grab bar at the same height as the bars inside the shower. It is screwed into a stud on each end. (The house is framed on 24" centers.) So the shower is in effect fitted with four grab bars, three inside and one just outside.

EDIT4

Another consideration for grab bars in showers is that one does not drill into electrical cables (or other things) For example, the long wall of my tub/shower contains the electrical cables for both the clothes washer and the clothes dryer and the vent for the dryer. So there was a benefit to using anchors between the studs for the 36" grab bar-- after I drilled the hole into space (not into a stud), I was able to insert a probe through the hole and assure myself there was no electrical cable in the way of the sharp ends of the screws I was going to drive in.

N.B. When screwing into a stud the hole in the ceramic tile should be significantly larger in diameter than the "pilot" hole for the screw in the stud behind the ceramic and larger than the threads on the screw. One does not want the threads of the screws to contact the ceramic tile because it could crack or loosen a tile.

I use the same size ceramic drill as for the plastic anchors just through the tile and backer, then change to the smaller wood drill bit appropriate for the pilot hole in the stud. Before putting up the grab bar flange I insert the cut off end of an anchor to seal the hole to prevent water ingress. I use silicone or wax thread lubricant to ease turning the screws in the pilot holes in the studs.

Answer (score 3):

If the wall in question is an interior wall, you could simply locate the bar in its optimum position (which may or may not be where a stud is), drill your holes, and drill all the way through to the other side of the wall.  Then open up the wall, install blocking for the screws, then repair the drywall.

Comment: This is an ingenious suggestion that never occurred to me. In my case the clothes washer and dryer are across that wall so the the access holes for blocking would be hidden behind the washer and dryer. The access holes could be closed with the plastic access ports with removable door for future inspection or work.